# run mmc.exe services.msc " from iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

http://www.lansweeper.com/ has features that let user do some actions such as Remote Computer management and etc from web application. I need to deploy it in my Asp.Net c# web application. I do it by the code blow when I build my project it works but when I trying to run it from IIS it doesn't works, just nothing happens.

Any help and idea please. No error encountered

```
protected void lnkComputermanagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        long InfoID = Convert.ToInt64(txtInfoID.Text);
        IBAPanel.NetworkSupport.WMIInfo WMIInfo = new IBAPanel.NetworkSupport.WMIInfo();
        WMIInfo = WMIInfo.Get(Convert.ToInt32(InfoID));
        string ComName = WMIInfo.ComputerName1;
        string Pass = WMIInfo.Password;

        if (WMIInfo.UserName != "" && WMIInfo.ComputerName1 != "" && WMIInfo.Password != "")
        {
            string Usname = WMIInfo.UserName.Substring(2);

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Process myprocess = new Process();
            myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myprocess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myprocess.StartInfo.UserName = Usname;
            myprocess.StartInfo.Password = MakeSecureString(Pass);
            myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C mmc.exe compmgmt.msc /computer:" + ComName;
            myprocess.Start();
            myprocess.Close();
        }

        Response.Redirect("content.aspx?lan=fa&gid=524&InfoID=" + InfoID);

        ActionJquery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder cstext1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append(" $(document).ready(function () {");
        cstext1.Append("alert(" + ex.Message + ")  ");
        cstext1.Append(" });  ");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "", cstext1.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i need to run cmd from iis but HOW?

Comment: For a start your code doesn't seem to try to capture the output, so assuming it does run on the IIS server the output will just appear in a window and disappear. Edit to add - I mean a window on the server, not anything the end-user will see.

Comment: myProcess.StandardOutput will give you the reference to a stream of where the process sends it output. You can read that stream and then use the data to send to the aspx page.

Comment: Take a look at StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput for a start but you'll need more work to get that returned on a web page. You need to get the stream and get it back to the client, as ryadavilli said.

Comment: Guys i should edit the Question, please read it again!

Comment: This is a click-once application? If there's nothing running on your client system other than a web browser, then this will never work i.e. if you're invoking that click action on the iis server then the cmd command is running on the web server, getting that to work and display on the client system is pretty much not going to happen without a huge amount of work. I can put much more detail in an answer if you want, but it will pretty much amount to just more details on the whys and wherefores of it not working

Comment: do you have any experience on the same problem as mine, if yes i appreciate you to post it in the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the command "mmc.exe" on the webserver and not on the client browsing the website.  If you look at the taskmanager on the webserver you will see multiple mmc.exe processes that are running.

Comment: OK HOW CAN I DO IT ON THE CLIENT?

Comment: You cannot do it on the client with asp.net because asp.net runs on the webserver and send html back to the client, most likely lansweeper uses something that runs on the client computer (java applet, active-x control, executable, ...)

Comment: Dear WilfriedVs i found some script that can handle my some actions , action that do not need credential but about actions need credential i stocked!!!

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833181/open-cmd-exe-with-different-credential-using-shellscripting

Answer (score 0):

To manage Windows Services from Web you need special permission and you can't go through Services.msc, you need to use WMI (Windows management instruments) and you need to give the application pool higher permission but the best way is to impersionate your piece of code where you fetch for sevices information.

A good open source project with full WMI usage is Services+ on codeplex:

[Services+ On CodePlex](https://servicesplus.codeplex.com/)

Thanks